# Managed Metadata Service insufficient permissions

Tags: 2016, term-store, managed-metadata-service

I am having an issue, where some of the term store admins are getting an error saying they have insufficient permissions to add, update and change terms and settings in here. Whereas some are still able to do so. I am lost as it looks like they all have the same permissions. These users are all farm admins for one.
What sort of things should i look into?

Answer (score 0):

Even though its a farm admin, It should provide access to MMS.please find the below link for more details and the solution for the issue.

1. Go to SharePoint Central Administration Site –> Application
   Management –> [Service Applications] –> Manage service applications
2. Highlight the Managed Metadata Service that your web application is associated with. (Do not click on the link, just click somewhere else on that row to highlight it)
3. Click on Permissions button in the ribbon area.
4. Add the application pool account used by your web application and give it  ‘full Access to Term Store’
5. Click OK.

Reference URL:

- [The current user has insufficient permissions to perform this operation when trying to add Term stored managed navigation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/8175c5e8-98bb-4da0-a8a3-09bf096c6e75/the-current-user-has-insufficient-permissions-to-perform-this-operation-when-trying-to-add-term?forum=sharepointgeneral).
- [Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available](http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.com/2014/08/managed-metadata-service-or-connection.html)
- http://www.lucacostante.com/item/20-how-to-resolve-the-current-user-has-insufficient-permissions-to-perform-this-operation-error-when-adding-termstore-through-a-timerjob.html

Comment: Thanks but i've tried and it doesn't work. Also doesn't explain why its not an issue for some termstore admins, do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: Ohh is it... not faced similar issue .. if I get any helpful information about this, will update it here :-)

Comment: thanks so much :)